# libpng with directory tree zlib build error

Tags: c++, cmake, libpng

I have the following cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

add_subdirectory(googletest)
add_subdirectory(zlib)

# libpng setup
option(PNG_TESTS OFF)
set(PNG_TESTS OFF)
option(PNG_SHARED OFF)
set(PNG_SHARED OFF)
option(PNG_EXECUTABLES OFF)
set(PNG_EXECUTABLES OFF)
option(PNG_BUILD_ZLIB ON)
set(PNG_BUILD_ZLIB ON)
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/zlib" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/zlib")
set(ZLIB_LIBRARY "zlib")
add_subdirectory(libpng)
```

This generates the project correctly and `zlib`/`googletest` build is OK. `pnglib` on the other hand doesn't build:

```
1>Generating pnglibconf.out
1>Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29337 for x64
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>pnglibconf.c
1>build/thirdparty/libpng/pnglibconf.c(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory
1>CMake Error at scripts/genout.cmake:78 (message):
1>  Failed to generate build/thirdparty/libpng/pnglibconf.out.tf1
1>
1>
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(238,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'build\CMakeFiles\4c907688e112b5b30b06f56662306981\pnglibconf.out.rule;build\CMakeFiles\4c907688e112b5b30b06f56662306981\pnglibconf.h.rule;build\CMakeFiles\5a2501006db4b4e75991d2f2c16bfadf\sym.out.rule;build\CMakeFiles\4c907688e112b5b30b06f56662306981\libpng.sym.rule;build\CMakeFiles\5a2501006db4b4e75991d2f2c16bfadf\vers.out.rule;build\CMakeFiles\4c907688e112b5b30b06f56662306981\libpng.vers.rule;build\CMakeFiles\5a2501006db4b4e75991d2f2c16bfadf\intprefix.out.rule;build\CMakeFiles\5a2501006db4b4e75991d2f2c16bfadf\prefix.out.rule;build\CMakeFiles\5a2501006db4b4e75991d2f2c16bfadf\symbols.chk.rule;build\CMakeFiles\e5199c38ed750451ee22eda432b56e2c\genfiles.rule' exited with code 1.
1>Done building project "genfiles.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

If I manually copy `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/pnglibconf.h.prebuilt` to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pnglibconf.h` as `genfiles` target should do pnglib_static compiles fine.

```
...
if(NOT AWK OR ANDROID OR IOS)
  # No awk available to generate sources; use pre-built pnglibconf.h
  configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/scripts/pnglibconf.h.prebuilt
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pnglibconf.h)
  add_custom_target(genfiles) # Dummy
else()
...
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I would like to not alter the `CMakeLists.txt` from `libpng` to be easier to update to newer versions. I'm using the latest version from `url = git://git.code.sf.net/p/libpng/code` as documented on http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

Comment: Probably not the root cause, but you're missing a call to `project()` in your top-level, which is invalid.

Comment: @AlexReinking this CMakeLists.txt is included using `add_subdirectory`. In the main file there is a call to `project()`

Comment: I added a `project(test)` call to your CML, cloned all three repos, and was unable to repro from a Visual Studio command prompt. The project configured and built fine.

Answer (score 1):

After reading `genout.cmake` I've found this line:

```
set(AWK "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gawk.exe")
```

If I run CMake from `cmd` instead of `git bash` `genout.cmake` contains:

```
set(AWK "AWK-NOTFOUND")
```

Probably running CMake from `git bash` confuses the build system, but running CMake from `cmd` generates the project correctly.

Comment: Ah, that would be why I couldn't repro.

Comment: @AlexReinking I'll try to fix this and submit a patch. I've spent quite a lot of time finding out why it fails and maybe others will benefit